# Passing variables into a boolean expression within a dataframe query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataframe that need to iterate over and with each iteration I want to select rows of data where columns have values equal to the iterating index, and with each iteration I want to apply functions on the binned_dataframe it produces. The X_bin and Y_bin columns are filled with integer values varying from 0 to 10.

So it looks a bit like this

```
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
     
        binned_dataframe = dataframe.query('X_bin == i & Y_bin == j')
```

but this is throwing me

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'i' is not defined
```

However when I swap i and j for integers like this

```
binned_dataframe = dataframe.query('X_bin == 5 & Y_bin == 5')
```

it does work, so the problem seems to be in using a variable in the boolean. Does anyone know a way around this or a better way to select the data? I need a loop to apply these operations because in reality I have about 1500 different X_bin, Y_bin combinations .. please help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to apply string formatting to get the `i` and `j` values in the string:

```
binned_dataframe = dataframe.query(f'X_bin == {i} & Y_bin == {j}')
```